# Button click event not doing task as expected

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having these table :

tblLibraryItem : ItemID , MediaType , ItemName , DateAcquire , Status , CheckedOut , DueDate

tblMember : MemberID , FirstName , LastName , Email , Phone , DateBecameMember

There is checkout form, having two drop down :

1. Item ID Check Out : Shows a list of all ItemsIDs and Item Name from tblLibraryItem
2. Member ID Checked out to : Shows the Member ID, Member First Name and Last Name.

Now There is button to perform following tasks :

1. If the ItemID in the ItemID combo box is blank, we need to display a message and exit the sub without doing anything else.
2. If the MemberID in the MemberID combo box is blank, we need to display a message and exit the sub without doing anything else.
3. For the ItemID selected, check the status of the Item. If the status is “Checked Out”, display a message that the item is already checked out and exit the sub without doing anything else.

Here is my code :

```
Dim ItemName As String
Dim MemberID As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim FirstName As String

Dim currDatabase As DAO.Database
Set currDatabase = CurrentDb

Dim rstLibraryItem As DAO.Recordset
Set rstLibraryItem = currDatabase.OpenRecordset("tblLibraryItem")

rstLibraryItem.MoveFirst

Do While Not rstLibraryItem.EOF
If rstLibraryItem("ItemID") = CheckedOut Then Exit Do
  rstLibraryItem.MoveNext
Loop



cboItemIDCheckOut.SetFocus
ItemID = cboItemIDCheckOut.Text

cboMemberIDCheckedOutTo.SetFocus
MemberID = cboMemberIDCheckedOutTo.Text


If cboItemIDCheckOut.Text = "" Then
   MsgBox "Please select or type an ItemID"
Exit Sub
End If

If cboMemberIDCheckedOutTo.Text = "" Then
   MsgBox "Please select or type an MemberID"
Exit Sub
End If

If cboItemIDCheckOut.ItemID = "Checked Out" Then
   MsgBox "That item is already checked out"
Exit Sub
End If
```

But when I click on button I get error that Run time error 2185. You can't reference a property or method for a control unless control has the focus.

Am i doing something wrong ? Please help

Updating table gives error now :

```
Dim checkOuString As String
checkOuString = "Checked"
Dim updatLibItemSQL As String
updatLibItemSQL = "UPDATE [tblLibraryItem]"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " SET [Status] = [checkOuString] "
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = [selectItemID] "
currDatabase.Execute updatLibItemSQL, dbFailOnError
```

It gives error that too few parameters in Execute statement. Please help to correct it

Comment: Perhaps if you set the focus of that control to true you wouldn't get the error again?

Comment: where does CheckedOut  come from? Have you set Option Explicit?

Comment: new problem = new post ... and next time please show all your code because it's annoying if we have to guess or ask back several times! Where do checkOuString and selectItemID come from? In your code it would presume that they are fields of the table but I GUESS (because I do not know the rest of your code ) that these are vars / controls. In this case they have to be outside the sql and only the value of them has to be concated to the string - not the var names.

Answer (score 0):

use the .Value property instead of .Text

then you can throw away the .SetFocus and everything should work :)

Comment: See edited post. Finding some problem while updating status column corresponding to selected ItemID