# Update table statement not working on Button click

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having this code to update a table, but it gives error that too few arguments. Expected 2.

```
Dim currDatabase As DAO.Database
Set currDatabase = CurrentDb()
Dim updatLibItemSQL As String
updatLibItemSQL = "UPDATE [tblLibraryItem]"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " SET [Status] = [checkOuString] "
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = [selectItemID] "
currDatabase.Execute updatLibItemSQL, dbFailOnError
```

What can be reason ? Please help

Here tblLibraryItem is table name with given columns :  ItemID , MediaType , ItemName , DateAcquire , Status , CheckedOut , DueDate

And checkOuString,selectItemID are two Strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button click event not doing task as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975404/button-click-event-not-doing-task-as-expected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If checkOuString and selectItemID are string variables, the following may work

```
Dim currDatabase As DAO.Database
Set currDatabase = CurrentDb()
Dim updatLibItemSQL As String
updatLibItemSQL = "UPDATE [tblLibraryItem]"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " SET [Status] = '" & checkOuString & "'"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & selectItemID & "'"
currDatabase.Execute updatLibItemSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're executing updates through code, if you're passing variables to SQL strings, it's generally best to pass them through independent of the SQL string itself:

```
Dim currDatabase As DAO.Database
Set currDatabase = CurrentDb()
Dim updatLibItemSQL, CheckOuString, selectItemID As String
CheckOuString = "whatever value"
selectItemID = "whatever value"
updatLibItemSQL = "UPDATE [tblLibraryItem]"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " SET [Status] = '" & checkOuString &  "'"
updatLibItemSQL = updatLibItemSQL & " WHERE [ItemID] = '" & selectItemID & "'"
currDatabase.Execute updatLibItemSQL, dbFailOnError
```